# Panda dataframe into databse,TypeError: Required argument 'database' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I want to insert pd dataframe into database with sqlite3 with Python3

```
df = pd.DataFrame(maindatatable)
print (df)

con = sqlite3.connect(host="localhost",user="milenko",passwd="******",db="dbase")
sql.write_frame(df, con=con, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')

It doesn't work
  File "b23.py", line 36, in <module>
    con = sqlite3.connect(host="localhost",user="milenko",passwd="*******",db="dbase")
TypeError: Required argument 'database' (pos 1) not found
```

If I go back to MySQL

```
show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| ap1                |
| classicmodels      |
| dbase              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

dbase is here,so what is wrong?

If I change to

```
con = sqlite3.connect("dbase")
```

then

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.sql' has no attribute 'write_frame'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlite3.connect("dbase")
```

just use this line, you dont need all those

Comment: if you are using mysql then you need mysql connector to connect bro not sqlite3